# magento 1 to magento 2 data migration issue

Tags: magento2, magento1.9.2.4, data-migration, magento2.2.3, data-migration-tool

> PCS118@PCS118 MINGW64 `/d/Projects/xampp/htdocs/magento2`
>   `$ php bin/magento migrate:data  -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml`
>
> ---
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:05][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started ?[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:12][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_CATALOG_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 121,164 from `catalog_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`? [0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:12][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 121 from `catalog_product_entity_int`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:12][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 121,163,164 from `eav_entity_attribute`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`?[0m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:12][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started ?[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:13][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: customer_eav_attribute. Fields: is_used_for_customer_segment?[0m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:13][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:13][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started ?[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source documents are not mapped: paybox_question_number,social_facebook_actions,strikeiron_tax_rate?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Destination documents are not mapped: mageplaza_helloworld_post,tbl_booking?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: cms_page. Fields: published_revision_id,website_root,under_version_control?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_creditmemo. Fields: base_customer_balance_amount,customer_balance_amount,bs_customer_bal_total_refunded,customer_bal_total_refunded,base_gift_cards_amount,gift_cards_amount,gw_base_ price,gw_price,gw_items_base_price,gw_items_price,gw_card_base_price,gw_card_price,gw_base_tax_amount,gw_tax_amount,gw_items_base_tax_amount,gw_items_tax_amount,gw_card_base_tax_amount,gw_card_tax_amount,base_reward_currency_amount,reward_currency_amount,reward_points_ba lance,reward_points_balance_refund?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_invoice. Fields: base_customer_balance_amount,customer_balance_amount,base_gift_cards_amount,gift_cards_amount,gw_base_price,gw_price,gw_items_base_price,gw_items_price,gw_card_base    _price,gw_card_price,gw_base_tax_amount,gw_tax_amount,gw_items_base_tax_amount,gw_items_tax_amount,gw_card_base_tax_amount,gw_card_tax_amount,base_reward_currency_amount,reward_currency_amount,reward_points_balance?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order. Fields: base_customer_balance_amount,customer_balance_amount,base_customer_balance_invoiced,customer_balance_invoiced,base_customer_balance_refunded,customer_balance_refunded ,bs_customer_bal_total_refunded,customer_bal_total_refunded,gift_cards,base_gift_cards_amount,gift_cards_amount,base_gift_cards_invoiced,gift_cards_invoiced,base_gift_cards_refunded,gift_cards_refunded,gw_id,gw_allow_gift_receipt,gw_add_card,gw_base_price,gw_price,gw_ite ms_base_price,gw_items_price,gw_card_base_price,gw_card_price,gw_base_tax_amount,gw_tax_amount,gw_items_base_tax_amount,gw_items_tax_amount,gw_card_base_tax_amount,gw_card_tax_amount,gw_base_price_invoiced,gw_price_invoiced,gw_items_base_price_invoiced,gw_items_price_inv oiced,gw_card_base_price_invoiced,gw_card_price_invoiced,gw_base_tax_amount_invoiced,gw_tax_amount_invoiced,gw_items_base_tax_invoiced,gw_items_tax_invoiced,gw_card_base_tax_invoiced,gw_card_tax_invoiced,gw_base_price_refunded,gw_price_refunded,gw_items_base_price_refund ed,gw_items_price_refunded,gw_card_base_price_refunded,gw_card_price_refunded,gw_base_tax_amount_refunded,gw_tax_amount_refunded,gw_items_base_tax_refunded,gw_items_tax_refunded,gw_card_base_tax_refunded,gw_card_tax_refunded,reward_points_balance,base_reward_currency_amo unt,reward_currency_amount,base_rwrd_crrncy_amt_invoiced,rwrd_currency_amount_invoiced,base_rwrd_crrncy_amnt_refnded,rwrd_crrncy_amnt_refunded,reward_points_balance_refund,reward_points_balance_refunded,reward_salesrule_points?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order_address. Fields: giftregistry_item_id?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order_item. Fields: event_id,giftregistry_item_id,gw_id,gw_base_price,gw_price,gw_base_tax_amount,gw_tax_amount,gw_base_price_invoiced,gw_price_invoiced,gw_base_tax_amount_invoiced, gw_tax_amount_invoiced,gw_base_price_refunded,gw_price_refunded,gw_base_tax_amount_refunded,gw_tax_amount_refunded,qty_returned?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote. Fields: customer_balance_amount_used,base_customer_bal_amount_used,use_customer_balance,gift_cards,gift_cards_amount,base_gift_cards_amount,gift_cards_amount_used,base_gift_c ards_amount_used,gw_id,gw_allow_gift_receipt,gw_add_card,gw_base_price,gw_price,gw_items_base_price,gw_items_price,gw_card_base_price,gw_card_price,gw_base_tax_amount,gw_tax_amount,gw_items_base_tax_amount,gw_items_tax_amount,gw_card_base_tax_amount,gw_card_tax_amount,us e_reward_points,reward_points_balance,base_reward_currency_amount,reward_currency_amount?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote_address. Fields: base_customer_balance_amount,customer_balance_amount,gift_cards_amount,base_gift_cards_amount,gift_cards,used_gift_cards,giftregistry_item_id,gw_id,gw_allow_g ift_receipt,gw_add_card,gw_base_price,gw_price,gw_items_base_price,gw_items_price,gw_card_base_price,gw_card_price,gw_base_tax_amount,gw_tax_amount,gw_items_base_tax_amount,gw_items_tax_amount,gw_card_base_tax_amount,gw_card_tax_amount,reward_points_balance,base_reward_c urrency_amount,reward_currency_amount?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote_address_item. Fields: gw_id,gw_base_price,gw_price,gw_base_tax_amount,gw_tax_amount?[0m ?[0;33m[2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote_item. Fields: event_id,giftregistry_item_id,gw_id,gw_base_price,gw_price,gw_base_tax_amount,gw_tax_amount?[0m ?[0;33m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: wishlist. Fields: name,visibility?[0m
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:17][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started ?[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:26][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: started ?[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:29][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started ?[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started ?[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
>
> [2018-04-02 09:16:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step]: started ?[2K13% [===>------------------------] Remaining Time: 1 mins
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '700-419' for key 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'
>
> `migrate:data [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] [--] <config>`

Answer (score 3):

First take a backup of your Magento1 database.

Please remove orphans record from your Magento1 database. after you solve **Foreign key** error.

Remove 121,164 `attribut_id` row from `catalog_eav_attribute`.

Remove 121 `attribut_id` row from `catalog_product_entity_int`.

Remove 121,163,164 `attribut_id` row from `eav_entity_attribute`.

**Source fields are not mapped.**

Please add code in `map.xml.dist` source part.

```
<ignore><field>customer_eav_attribute.is_used_for_customer_segment</field></ignore>
```

**Source documents are not mapped.** Please add code in `map.xml.dist` source part.

```
<ignore><document>paybox_question_number</document></ignore>
<ignore><document>social_facebook_actions</document></ignore>
<ignore><document>strikeiron_tax_rate</document></ignore>
```

Follow this step for all of your source/destination issue.

Once you drop your database and execute this process again after complete this step.

I hope this will help you.